# Data not appearing in MongoDB after bulk insert?

Tags: python, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I'm currently working with MongoDB running inside Azure CosmosDB to serve as a data store for an API. For my use case, I process a 30MB .csv file with approx. 180000 rows once per day. Due to this project still being in the proof-of-concept stage, my CosmosDB instance is limited to a maximum of 4000 RUs/s. I also set the shard key to be the date corresponding to the insert.

I have distributed each 'batch' of data to be 100 documents each, sending each second. This process runs overnight so a long insert time not a concern. It takes roughly an hour to insert all the documents. I performed a dry-run today and was monitoring the documents being inserted through MongoDB Compass. As the process was running, I could see more and more documents were getting added to the collection as I refreshed, but once the process finished, both Compass and the CosmosDB Explorer reported there were no documents whatsoever in the collection. My question is, *what could have happened here?* As far as I know, I didn't experience rate limiting of any kind, and have still been charged for the insert operation.

I process and load the batches with Python and pymongo. I have `except` blocks set up to catch `BulkWriteError`s, but no errors were reported by the script. The code for loading is as follows:

```py
for n in range(0, len(records), 100):
    time.sleep(INTERVAL)
    batch_slice = records[n:n+100]
    batch_reqs = [
        pymongo.InsertOne(row)
        for row in batch_slice
    ]

    try:
        collection.bulk_write(batch_reqs, ordered=False)
    except BulkWriteError as e:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who may inadvertently find this page, my issue was that I had set a time-to-live of 128 seconds on all my documents in the collection through Terraform, so they were being deleted 128 seconds after being inserted. Changing the value to `-1` fixed the issue.

Kind of embarrassing I didn't spot this straight away, but it's one of those things that can be easily missed, I guess.